# AWS Lambda function running custom executable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, executable

I have need to run a custom file parser to parse incoming files live for further upstream use. The parser is an executable and takes some arguments. I have written the following lambda test function:

```
import subprocess, sys
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    path = os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']
    subprocess.call([path+'/*exefile*',*args*])
```

However I get an error, and this is even without any input, meaning it's not related to the writing of new files in the lambda environment:

```
PermissionError errno13 Permission denied
```

It seems to me that it's simply not allowed to run the executable. For the IAM role I have given it the full lambda access. The custom exe file is not compiled for linux, but wouldn't I get another error if that was the issue?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Per this [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/) it needs to compiled for Amazon's Linux:

> If you compile your own binaries, ensure that they’re either
>   statically linked or built for the matching version of Amazon Linux.
>   The current version of Amazon Linux in use within AWS Lambda can
>   always be found on the Supported Versions page of the Lambda docs.

Comment: Okay thanks, I though that issue might produce a different error.